# Toggle clickable element style in accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

This is doing my head in.  Sorry if it's a schoolboy error.  I have a very straight forward jquery accordion and I can toggle a style on the clickable header for each content by adding a class, but the class does not go when I click to collapse that element itself, only when I expand a sibling.  I've popped this on jsfiddle with a simple colour switch.

```
   $(document).ready(function ($) {
       $('#showHideAccordion').find('h2').click(function () {
           $('.active').removeClass('active');
            //Expand or collapse this panel
           $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
           $(this).toggleClass('active');
            //Hide the other panels
           $(".podContent").not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow').removeClass('active');
       });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wf73o6c6/

Comment: Your 3rd line with `$('.active').removeClass('active');` spoil all of `toggleClass` work. Remove this line and everything will be fine

Comment: It works for me. It expands and collapse when I click on the same element.

Comment: Expand works but `active` blue color of `h1` is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the already active item, you remove the `active` class from it with this line:
`$('.active').removeClass('active');`
then you add it again with this line:
`$(this).toggleClass('active');`

Making this change to the first line will fix it:
`$('.active').not($(this)).removeClass('active');`
This way you remove the active class from all the *other* items, and with the `toggleClass` line that comes after, you remove the class from the clicked item.

You don't need to remove the class again on your last line, you already took care of that (I see you already used the `.not()` function here, so your mistake was probably just lack of attention).
`$(".podContent").not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');`

Also, unrelated, but why `$('#showHideAccordion').find('h2')` and not just `$('#showHideAccordion h2')` ?

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wf73o6c6/2/

Comment: Hi Talya,  thank you so very much!! It makes perfect sense looking at it now.  Many many thanks,